# React: how to declare routes inside a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

First off, I tried searching for this issue before I posted but couldn't find a solution for a similar use case.

So I have a component called App.js where I define all my top level routes:

```
<TransitionGroup>
    <CSSTransition key={location.key} mountOnEnter={true} unMountOnExit={true} timeout={800} classNames="fade-up-down">
        <Switch location={location}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/artists" component={Artists} />
            <Route path="/artworks/:slug" component={Artwork} />
        </Switch>
    </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

Now, inside the home component, I want to have my second level of routes, which I didn't do in `App.js` because I had props to pass from `Home.js` to the child components. The routes portion in my `Home.js` looks like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Map {...props} artworks={artworks} />} />
    <Route exact path="/grid" render={(props) => <Grid {...props} artworks={artworks} />} />
    <Route exact path="/rainbow" render={(props) => <Rainbow {...props} artworks={artworks} />} />
</Switch>
```

The second level routes inside `Home.js` work fine, but when I try to go to any of the other top level routes, eg. `/artists/` or `/about`, they do not work.

Can someone please point me to the right direction here? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you giving a location props to your App switch ?

Comment: @Axnyff because I need to change body backgrounds depending on the `location.pathname` string.

Comment: It's inject as a props in the sub component or you can use `useLocation` to make it work. Giving that prop to a switch is a mean to override the normal routing. Can you try without that prop ?

Comment: @Axnyff just tried without the location prop, still doesn't work.

Comment: Something must be off, how can your subroutes in Home work if your routing is exact at the Home ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is it possible the way you want.
I think you are overriding the App Router when you navigate to you Home component.
Your routes has to be on a top lvl of your App

Comment: I definetely have an app with nested routing like his so i'm sure it's not a problem

Comment: @Axnyff will you be able to show me a working example of this so that I have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-proskuriakova-iuo7k?file=/src/App.js This works correctly with nested routing

Answer (score 0):

Moving the routes after the first one from to the top worked. Here's how it looks now:

```
<TransitionGroup>
    <CSSTransition key={location.key} mountOnEnter={true} unMountOnExit={true} timeout={800} classNames="fade-up-down">
        <Switch location={location}>
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/artists" component={Artists} />
            <Route path="/artworks/:slug" component={Artwork} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
    </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```